# "You do not have sufficient access to your computer to connect to the selected printer"

Tags: windows-xp, printing

We have a lab of Windows XP based systems trying to connect to a printer on a windows 2003 system.

A group of users...and it seems to be limited to this lab...are getting the error "You do not have sufficient access to your computer to connect to the selected printer" when they open Explorer, enter \printers (our printer server) into the address bar and hit enter then right click on the printer they want and select connect. Using adprintx returns an error -4048.

This isn't a terminal server, and they're connecting via the local workstation, not over terminal services.

Google searches seem to keep linking this to problems with domain controllers and using terminal services. Any other idea what would be causing this? Nothing else is appearing in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that the users have the install printer priviledge, although I guess you have already done that.

I think this might be a problem caused by drivers that arn't 100% standard. It may not work for you in this instance but one thing that has solved this error for me in the past is if you add the printer (and install the drivers) once as an admin user on each machine then the regular users, without admin rights, can then add the printer themselves.

Comment: We implemented a change in active directory that was outlined here and haven't heard anything back from the people using that lab yet. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=319939&product=winsvr2003

Answer (score 1):

The issue often happens when the printer that you are trying to connect has lost connection with the Print Server (in my case was a shared network Printer).

I resolved the issue, by restarting the printer and ensuring its connected to the network and adding the printer over again.

PS: Make sure you are logged in as an administrator on the PC - Play safe.